# Is 'print' key word? How to describe this shell command with string of python?

Tags: python, shell

Some error are reported, when `format` string that is a shell command.

The python code:

```
str = "jps | grep {0} | grep -v {1} | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill -9".format(1,2)
```

The error information:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> KeyError: 'print'
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
>>> "jps | grep {0} | grep -v {1} | awk '{{print $1}}' | xargs kill -9".format(1,2)
"jps | grep 1 | grep -v 2 | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill -9"
```

Comment: Can you explain why this is the correct solution?

Answer (score 1):

### Answering the title

In Python 2.7, `print` is a keyword.  In Python 3.x, it is not.

### Fixing the code

```
"jps | grep {0} | grep -v {1} | awk '{{print $1}}' | xargs kill -9".format(1,2)
```

### Why

When you wrap a value inside of extra `{}` in format, it will interpret the string literally, not trying to replace it.